# How to let Django's generic view use a form with initial values?

Tags: python, django, forms

I know how to set initial values to a form from the view. But how do I go about letting a generic view set initial values to a form? I can write a wrapper view for the generic view, but I still have no access to the form object instantiation.

The specific goal I'm trying to achieve is to have a user create a new object, using the create_object generic view. However, I'd like to set a field of the object 'user' to the currently logged in user, which is only accessible as request.user. How can the form be initialized to have this field?

Edit: I came across __new__. Could this call its own constructor with some default arguments?

Many thanks.

Comment: I don't really understand the purpose of this, but did you look at template_name and extra_content variables?

But seriously why not write an html page/form and stop trying to come up with crazy round about generic ways of doing this. If you need to set some particular value (like user) in a form, you are already programming for a very specific case.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, you cannot achieve this behavior through Django's `create_object` generic view; you will have to write your own.  However, this is rather simple.

To start off, you must create a new form class, like this:

```
from django import forms
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel  # model has a user field
```

Then you would be able to create a view like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def create_mymodel(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Get data from form
        form = MyForm(request.POST)
        # If the form is valid, create a new object and redirect to it.
        if form.is_valid():
            newObject = form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(newObject.get_absolute_url())
    else:
        # Fill in the field with the current user by default
        form = MyForm(initial={'user': request.user})
    # Render our template
    return render_to_response('path/to/template.html',
        {'form': form},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew about this already, but the generic view is so tantalizing that it couldn't work with initial values.

Comment: I agree: the generic views are great, but if you want to set defaults, it's a nightmare.  And I whole-heartedly agree with Carl Meyer's post.

Answer (score 3):

You could do this in a generic view wrapper by dynamically constructing a form class and passing it to the generic view, but that cure is probably worse than the disease.  Just write your own view, and wait eagerly for [this](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/6735) to land.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the features of the generic view then you can just create a new generic view using the original as a template.

Eg:

```
def create_object_with_initial(request, model=None, template_name=None,
    template_loader=loader, extra_context=None, post_save_redirect=None,
    login_required=False, context_processors=None, form_class=None, initial=None):

if extra_context is None: extra_context = {}
if login_required and not request.user.is_authenticated():
    return redirect_to_login(request.path)

model, form_class = get_model_and_form_class(model, form_class)
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = form_class(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        new_object = form.save()

        msg = ugettext("The %(verbose_name)s was created successfully.") %\
                                {"verbose_name": model._meta.verbose_name}
        messages.success(request, msg, fail_silently=True)
        return redirect(post_save_redirect, new_object)
else:
    print "creating", form_class, " with initial data ", initial
    form = form_class(initial=initial)

# Create the template, context, response
if not template_name:
    template_name = "%s/%s_form.html" % (model._meta.app_label, model._meta.object_name.lower())
t = template_loader.get_template(template_name)
c = RequestContext(request, {
    'form': form,
}, context_processors)
apply_extra_context(extra_context, c)
return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

This is copied from /site-packages/django/views/generic/create_update.py with only lines 3 and 21 changing to incorporate the initial data.

Then use it as you might expect:

```
object_info = {
'model': YourModel,
'initial': {'data' : 'Initial Value'},
'template_name': 'template.html'
}

url(r'^path/$',
    login_required(create_object_with_initial),
    object_info,
    name='url_name'),
```

That should work.