# How to set ForeignKey in CreateView?

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I have a model:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

How do I write class-based view that creates a new model instance and sets `author` foreign key to `request.user`?

**Update:**

Solution moved to separate [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10565744/1061572) below.

Comment: absolutely the best solution!

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I solved this by overriding `form_valid` method. Here is verbose style to clarify things:

```
class CreateArticle(CreateView):
    model = Article

    def form_valid(self, form):
        article = form.save(commit=False)
        article.author = self.request.user
        #article.save()  # This is redundant, see comments.
        return super(CreateArticle, self).form_valid(form)
```

Yet we can make it short (thanks dowjones123), this case is [mentioned in docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#models-and-request-user).:

```
class CreateArticle(CreateView):
    model = Article

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super(CreateArticle, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: +1 for doing it properly. All other methods of using HiddenInput or setting initials would be a potential security risk.

Comment: This is not ideal, as it results in the form's `save` method being called twice. This is one of those cases where your best choice is to re-implement the rest of the `super` method, vs delegating. In other words, set `self.object` to the new instance, then redirect to `self.get_success_url()`.

Comment: @orokusaki You are absolutely right. I looked through the source code and found that `form_valid` does nothing except saving (already validated) form instance. So we can safely remove either `super` or `save` line. The latter is better as we don't need to think about the `success_url` (otherwise we need to set it explicitly). Corrected the answer.

Comment: @VladT. it's still technically incorrect, because the save method of the form is still being called twice (the first with `commit=False`), and a form's save method could have logic in it (or even just logging) that you might not want to run twice. If you add back the `article.save()` and replace the `super(...)` line with `return redirect(self.get_success_url())`, that will be the most correct solution.

Comment: @orokusaki This is not so straightforward, because `form_valid` also sets `self.object`. Without that you cannot access view's object in other methods in case you want to override them. Also, by the same reason you are not able to run `get_success_url` and have to set it explicitly, as I mentioned above. As for `form.save` method, if you need to integrate some logic in it you can always check the `commit` flag.

Comment: a slightly more efficient way (viewpoints may differ) would be to have replace first two lines of `form_valid` by `form.instance.author = self.request.user`

Comment: @dowjones123 You may be right, but my case is what [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) recommends (see `commit=False` part).

Comment: @VladT. I am following this doc only here we map an author to requested user that's good. what if i want to map a city to a hotel (HotelModel contain city with ForeignKey to CityModel). How do i do that?. i am getting error `No City matches the given query.`

Answer (score 15):

I just stumbled into this problem and this thread led me in the right direction (thank you!). Based on [this Django documentation page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#models-and-request-user), we can avoid calling the form's `save()` method at all:

```
class CreateArticle(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Article

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super(CreateArticle, self).form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should set up a `CreateView` using a `ModelForm` for that model. In the form definition, you set the `ForeignKey` to have the `HiddenInput` widget, and then use the `get_form` method on the view to set the value of your user:

forms.py:

```
from django import forms

class ArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        widgets = {"user": forms.HiddenInput()}
```

views.py:

```
from django.views.generic import *
from myapp.forms import ArticleForm
from myapp.models import Article

class NewArticleView(CreateView):
    model = Article
    form_class = ArticleForm
    def get_form(self, form_class):
        initials = {
            "user": self.request.user
        }
        form = form_class(initial=initials)
        return form
```

Comment: I tried this code, but it does not pass user to view, and I cannot save new article (since `user` fiedl is requied). Instead I used form_valid method in CBV (see UPDATE in question. Anyway, thanks for having time for help!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "does not pass user to view"? It passed the user's ID and puts in in the hidden field "user". If you need the user elsewhere in the view (i.e. template), it's already in the `request` variable.

Comment: I tried your code again: I can't find any hidden input in the page source (except csrf token). And why do you think this field will be the user's ID? Why not username?

Comment: Or maybe this just CBV problem? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/907858/how-to-let-djangos-generic-view-use-a-form-with-initial-values#comment716057_908038

Comment: Damn, my code was wrong. Fixed it now. Note the error in the method name.

Comment: I confirm that, as **jantoniomartin** said, this code passes request.user.id with hidden field to template, but I can't save the form.

Answer (score 2):

Berislav's code in views.py doesn't work for me. The form is rendered as expected, with the user value in a hidden input, but the form is not saved (I don't know why). I have tried a slightly different approach, that works for me:

#### views.py

```
from django.views.generic import *
from myapp.forms import ArticleForm
from myapp.models import Article

class NewArticleView(CreateView):
    model = Article
    form_class = ArticleForm
    def get_initial(self):
        return {
            "user": self.request.user
        }
```

Comment: Should it be 'get_initial'?

Comment: Let's see, what if I modify HTML code and inject ANY user id in the form, how can you protect from such attack with your method?

Comment: @RichardCorden is right, it's `get_initial` (without the `s`)

Answer (score 1):

There are answers that are mainly related to the `User` model foreign key. However, let's suppose a simple scenario in which there is a model `Comment` containing a foreign key of the `Article` model, and you need to have a `CreateView` for `Comment` where each comment will have a foreign key of the `Article` model. In that case, the `Article` id would probably be in the `URL`, for example, `/article/<article-id>/comment/create/`. Here is how you can deal with such a scenario

```
class CommentCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Comment
    # template_name, etc 


    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.article = get_object_or_404(Article, pk=self.kwargs['article_id'])
        return super(CommentCreateView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)


    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.article= self.article    # if the article is not a required field, otherwise you can use the commit=False way
        return super(CommentCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```