# How to set a model field based on the current user in a Django CreateView

Tags: django, django-forms, django-orm, django-generic-views

I have the following view:

```
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView

from news.forms import CreateNewsStoryForm
from news.models import NewsStory


class CreateNewsStoryView(CreateView):
    model = NewsStory
    form_class = CreateNewsStoryForm
```

All you need to know about the `NewsStory` model, is that it has an `author` foreign key field to `User`. When a new NewsStory is created through the form, I want the new model's `author` attribute to be set to the current user. How do I hook into the `CreateView`'s flow to set this up?

I'm certain it must be somewhere in the view, since the form doesn't have access to the request.

This seems like it would be a very common use case, but I can't seem to figure out the correct keywords to search for this, so excuse me if it has been asked before.

Comment: Do remember to add a [python] tag. It'll help you get more views on your question. Regards.

Comment: @ Alasdair I think this question is phrased in a sufficiently different way that it could be useful to people looking for the answer.

Comment: Eeek, bigblind. You pinged me. The right way to ping @Alasdair is like this.

Comment: Thx @BhargavRao (And I'm sorry for pinging you again if this frustrates you :)).

Comment: Heh, Nope. I'm a lonely guy, you can ping me all day. But note that a question being phrased  *in a sufficiently different way* doesn't warrant opening of a duplicate. Do(es) the answer(s) in the other post answer your query?

Comment: Your question is a pretty common one on Stack Overflow, [here is another example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382838/how-to-set-foreignkey-in-createview). The question I chose has the advantage of being written by Russell, the guy who added CBVs to Django. Even if your answer is worded differently, it can still be marked as a duplicate. Future visitors who find this page can click through.

Comment: @Alasdair Ah yes, that makes sense. Also, I thought about closing in the wrong way. This is exactly the reason why SO has the closing mechanism. The way the question is phrased may add value, but the content shouldn't be duplicated. Deleting the dupe would remove value from the site.