# Django auto-populate user in Createview

Tags: django

I was wondering about the best way to creating a model and having the `request.user` auto populate a field.

model.py

```
class Match(models.Model):
    match_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    player = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=match_game, default=2)
    time_start = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, default=None, null=True)
    match_join = models.ForeignKey(User, default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    match_finished = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('match:details', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.match_name
```

views.py

```
class MatchCreate(CreateView):
    model = Match
    fields = ['match_name', 'player']
```

The idea is, when you create a match, you as a user automatically join that match.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set ForeignKey in CreateView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382838/how-to-set-foreignkey-in-createview). It's also covered in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#models-and-request-user).

Comment: @solarissmoke Thanks! i was looking in the wrong part of the docs

Answer (score 2):

My python might be rusty, its been more than a year since I worked with Django.

As mentioned in the comments below by Daniel Roseman the `request` object is already available as a member on the view class.

You only need to grab the user from the `request` and feed that into the created `instance` before it is saved.  This could be done in [`form_valid()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.form_valid):

```
def form_valid(form):
    form.instance.match_join = self.request.user
    super(MatchCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Class-based views already assign the request to `self.request`, there's no need to do it explicitly in post.

Comment: awesome, I forgot... Thx

Comment: but how can i call match_name or inside form_valid(form) function?

Comment: It should be on `form.instance.match_name`; but now its four years ago that I worked with Django :)