# Adding an object to a specific foreign key using CreateView django

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

From my views:

```
class SongCreate(CreateView):
    model = Song
    fields = ['album', 'name']
```

My functionality of adding a song (this) to an album is inside the details template of an album A. However, I want  the input only be the name and not the album anymore since the song's album should automatically be "A." How do I make the code above behave such?

From my urls:

```
url(r'album/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/song/add/$', views.SongCreate.as_view(), name='song-add')
```

Comment: did you try to set default in models?

Comment: what would i put as default?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set ForeignKey in CreateView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382838/how-to-set-foreignkey-in-createview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `get_initial` method:

```
class SongCreate(CreateView):
    model = Song
    fields = ['album', 'name']

    def get_initial(self):
        return {
            'album': Album.objects.get(id=self.kwargs.get('pk')),
        }
```

Or you can use the `form_valid` method:

```
class SongCreate(CreateView):
    model = Song
    fields = ['name']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.album = Album.objects.get(id=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
        return super(SongCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```