# HTML select form with option to enter value does not store the entered value as object field in django

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-models, django-forms

I have a Django form in which I have several drop-down menus that have an option to enter a custom value. 
In order to enter a custom value, I am using the following implementation to toggle a textbox whenever the custom value is selected from this implementation http://jsfiddle.net/6nq7w/4/

Whenever I select an option from the dropdown list and save the form, the model's object value (In this case it is `EmployeeInformation.dept`) retains the value selected, but it is not the case if I enter a custom value.

In the below example, I use a chained dropdown implementation to load the Department based on the Department ID.

For example - Let's say while filling the form I select the value **Sales** then the value of `EmployeeInformation.dept = Sales`, whereas when I select the option as `Enter Manually` and enter a new value say `DeptXYZ` the Django model object does not take this manually entered value as the data for the field Dept.

models.py

```py
class EmployeeInformation(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield(max_length=30,null=False, blank=False)
    dept_id = models.ForeignKey(DepartmentInformation, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    dept = models.ForeignKey(SubDeptInformation, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    salary = models.DecimalField(null=True, blank=True, decimal_places=2, max_digits=10)
```

form.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script>
function toggleField(hideObj,showObj){
  hideObj.disabled=true;        
  hideObj.style.display='none';
  showObj.disabled=false;   
  showObj.style.display='inline';
  showObj.focus();
}
</script>
<body>
<form name="EmployeeInformation" action="#">
Department: <select name="browser" 
          onchange="if(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value=='Enter Manually'){
              toggleField(this,this.nextSibling);
              this.selectedIndex='0';
          }">
            <option></option>
            <option value="Enter Manually">[Enter Manually]</option>
            <option>HR</option>
            <option>Sales</option>
            <option>Finance</option>
        </select><input name="Dept" style="display:none;" disabled="disabled" 
            onblur="if(this.value==''){toggleField(this,this.previousSibling);}">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

views.py

```py
class AddEmployeeInfo(CreateView):
    model = EmployeeInformation
    form_class = EmployeeForm
    template_name = 'form.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('employee_list')
```

How can I store the manually entered value as the value of the model object field, ie., in my example `EmployeeInformation.dept.name`

Thanks for any help in advance !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DeptXYZ` or any department entered manually does not exist in the database.

`dept` has a ForeignKey relationship with `EmployeeInformation` model. Hence, to store `DeptXYZ` or any other department entered manually, the department should exist in the database. Since, `DeptXYZ` is not present in the database, Django is storing `null` instead.

To store `DeptXYZ` or any other department entered manually, you will need to create the corresponding department first. You will need to override the `form_valid()` method of `AddEmployeeInfo` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10565744/7969717) to create and save the manually entered department first.

Hope this help!