# How to use object.id to make another object, creator of the current object?

Tags: python, django, database, django-models

I have two models in my django application 'Client' and 'Installment'. Below is my models.py:

models.py

```
rom django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.urls import reverse
# Create your models here.


class Client(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    dob = models.SlugField(max_length = 100)
    CNIC = models.SlugField(max_length = 100)
    property_type = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    down_payment = models.IntegerField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('client_details',kwargs={ 'pk' : self.pk})

class Installment(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    installment_month = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    installment_amount = models.IntegerField()
    installment_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.installment_month

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('installment_confirmation')
```

and my views.py

view.py

```
# To create new client
class ClientCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Client
    fields = ['name', 'dob', 'CNIC', 'property_type', 'down_payment']


# To add new installment

class AddInstallmentView(CreateView):
    model = Installment
    #template_name = "property_details/addinstallment_form.html"
    fields = ['installment_month', 'installment_amount']
```

And the URL that I have to add a new installment is below:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', ClientListView.as_view(), name='client_list'),
    path('new/', ClientCreateView.as_view(), name='add_client'),
    path('<int:pk>/', ClientDetailView.as_view(), name='client_details'),
    path('<int:pk>/Add-Installment', AddInstallmentView.as_view(), name='add_installment'),
    path('confirmation/', views.installment_added, name='installment_confirmation'),
]
```

You can see that the URL for adding new installment is unique. For example,

```
/<local_server_addr>/<client.id>/Add-Installment (because of <int:pk> above)
```

I can create a new client and also I can add installment.

**But how to connect an installment to a particular client?**

**How to use this `client.id` as an owner of the current installment?**

It looks like, when one client is created, it is being assigned with some ID from django. Now, how can I use that ID to link it to the installment that I am going to add?

Comment: If it's for the current user you have the id in the request. Else you can just pass the client_id in the url as well

Comment: Can you please elaborate your point a bit. I didn't completely understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by overriding the `form_valid` method to set the `client.id` as the owner, this is solved in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382838/how-to-set-foreignkey-in-createview), but in this case we use the client id from the URL parameters:

```
# To add new installment
class AddInstallmentView(CreateView):
    model = Installment
    #template_name = "property_details/addinstallment_form.html"
    fields = ['installment_month', 'installment_amount']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # here you get the client id/pk from the url parameters
        form.instance.client = get_object_or_404(Client, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return super(AddInstallmentView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Then to get all the installments linked to a client you could do:

```
client = Client.objects.get(SOME_FILTER)
installments = client.installment_set.all()
```